# ExtJs 4.3 Ajax request avoid timeout

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to avoid the Timeout parameter while perform an Ajax request.

On the application I have a "Send button" in which I send the information to the Server as:

```
if (Ext.getCmp('bottomPanel').getForm().isValid()) {
   mask.show();
   Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'sendInfo.do',
       timeout: 30000,
       jsonData: {
           'businesDateString': businessDate,
           'incremental': incremental
       },
       success: doDwrCallbackForced, //edit: used for Ext.MessageBox.show(message)
       failure: failureCallBack //edit: used for Ext.MessageBox.show(error message)
});
```

But this process could take between 2 mins to 15/20 mins. And I want to call the method of the server only once.

Is there any way to avoid the timeout **(apart from timeout:1800000, - 30 mins- , in the Ajax.request call)**?

Can the TaskRunner object be useful for this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: set timeout to 0 which mean unlimited. BTW are you sure about this implementation . If ajax request is going to take 15 mins of time you should go for asynchronous request or web sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the timeout settings globally...

Without giving the reason for not using the timeout config on the ajax.request function, it is tough to give you a proper answer.

```
Ext.Ajax.timeout = 300000; // 300 seconds 
Ext.override(Ext.form.Basic, {     timeout: Ext.Ajax.timeout / 1000 });
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Server, {     timeout: Ext.Ajax.timeout });
Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, {     timeout: Ext.Ajax.timeout });
```